# Cannot get the number of words in a variable

Tags: java

I can successfully count the number of words in a phrase like:

```
int numWords = "I am testing".split(" ").length;
```

(It returns 3.)

However, I am getting a user input and storing it in a string, then trying to count the number of words in it but it ALWAYS returns 1, no matter what.

I'm getting user input with a `stringVariable = scanner.next();` and using

```
int numWords = stringVariable.split(" ").length;
```

to get the number of words. Let's say I type "I am testing". It will return 1. Why is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

next():

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to
>   scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

The default delimiter is whitespace so you're only reading the first word. Thus, it will only ever be one word. Try reading all the user input in a loop with hasNext() (with some type of termination condition) or use nextLine() to read an entire line's worth.

Answer (score 5):

Because `scanner.next()` is tokenizing on whitespace.

`scanner.nextLine()` on the other hand, will do what you're looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "I am testing";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
    String stringVariable = s.next();
    System.out.println(stringVariable);
    int numWords = stringVariable.split(" ").length;
    System.out.println(numWords);


    s = new Scanner(input);
    stringVariable = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(stringVariable);
    numWords = stringVariable.split(" ").length;
    System.out.println(numWords);


}
```

Output:

> I
>   1
>   I am testing
>   3

Answer (score 4):

I believe next() stops at whitespace, so it would only be getting "I".  Try using scanner.nextLine().

Answer (score 1):

```
I'm getting user input with a stringVariable = scanner.next();
```

This will always return one, Because next() stops when reached at whitespace. Use one of these
it will help you.

```
scanner.nextLine()
or
scanner.hasNext();
```

Inside a loop to read all the tokens